# Tree graph, in D3.js Where does x and y property came from?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is the JavaScript code:

```
d3.json("city.json", function (error, root) {
        var nodes = cluster.nodes(root);
        var links = cluster.links(nodes);

        console.log(nodes);
        console.log(links);

        var link = gCluster.selectAll(".link")
            .data(links)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", diagonal);
```

When I log the nodes and links, it says there are `x` and `y` properties:

[image]

And my json file is just this:

[image]

Where does these two properties came from?

Comment: I am sorry, but it isn't. I have re-edited my question and upload a pic. My json file does not contain such properties

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I see you're new here. Next time, please post your real code/data/log, not a screenshot of it. It's easier for people trying to answer your question and, therefore, better for you.

Comment: Sorry, I will change my way next time, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It's because of `d3.layout.cluster()`.

In your code, before that `d3.json` function, you probably have something like this:

```
var cluster = d3.layout.cluster();
```

Then, when you do:

```
var nodes = cluster.nodes(root);
var links = cluster.links(nodes);
```

You're calling `d3.layout.cluster()` over your data.

What does `d3.layout.cluster()` do? According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Cluster-Layout.md):

> These layouts follow the same basic structure: the input argument to the layout is the root node of the hierarchy, and the output return value is an array representing the computed positions of all nodes. **Several attributes** are populated on each node:
>
> - parent - the parent node, or null for the root.
> - children - the array of child nodes, or null for leaf nodes.
> - depth - the depth of the node, starting at 0 for the root.
> - x - the computed x-coordinate of the node position.
> - y - the computed y-coordinate of the node position.
>
> (emphasis mine)

And that's the origin of the new `x` and `y` properties in your data, as well as other properties (you can see `depth` in your screenshot).

**PS**: This is D3 v3.x. In D3 v4, `d3.layout.cluster()` has been changed, it's now `d3.cluster()`.