# What is meant by d.x and d.y in the following D3.js data passing example

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I would like to know what is meant by the following code 
**return d.x** and **d.y**. I do not see any data loaded into the function that has properties named x and y.

```
var w = 900,
    h = 400;

var circleWidth = 5;

var fontFamily = 'Bree Serif',
    fontSizeHighlight = '1.5em',
    fontSizeNormal = '1em';

var palette = {
      "lightgray": "#819090",
      "gray": "#708284",
      "mediumgray": "#536870",
      "darkgray": "#475B62",

      "darkblue": "#0A2933",
      "darkerblue": "#042029",

      "paleryellow": "#FCF4DC",
      "paleyellow": "#EAE3CB",
      "yellow": "#A57706",
      "orange": "#BD3613",
      "red": "#D11C24",
      "pink": "#C61C6F",
      "purple": "#595AB7",
      "blue": "#2176C7",
      "green": "#259286",
      "yellowgreen": "#738A05"
  }

var nodes = [
                {"name": "Matteo" },
                    {"name": "Daniele"},
                    {"name": "Marco"},
                    {"name": "Lucio"},
                    {"name": "Davide" }
  ]

var links = [
                {source: nodes[0], target: nodes[1]},
                  {source: nodes[1], target: nodes[2]},
                  {source: nodes[0], target: nodes[3]},
                  {source: nodes[4], target: nodes[2]},
  {source: nodes[2], target: nodes[3]}
]



var vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
      .attr("class", "stage")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links([])
    .gravity(0.1)
    .charge(-1000)
    .size([w, h]);

 var link = vis.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("stroke", "#CCC")
          .attr("fill", "none");

 var node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")

      //MOUSEOVER
      .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
        if (i>0) {
          //CIRCLE
          d3.select(this).selectAll("circle")
          .transition()
          .duration(250)
          .style("cursor", "none")     
          .attr("r", circleWidth+3)
          .attr("fill",palette.orange);

          //TEXT
          d3.select(this).select("text")
          .transition()
          .style("cursor", "none")     
          .duration(250)
          .style("cursor", "none")     
          .attr("font-size","1.5em")
          .attr("x", 15 )
          .attr("y", 5 )
        } else {
          //CIRCLE
          d3.select(this).selectAll("circle")
          .style("cursor", "none")     

          //TEXT
          d3.select(this).select("text")
          .style("cursor", "none")     
        }
      })

      //MOUSEOUT
      .on("mouseout", function(d,i) {
        if (i>0) {
          //CIRCLE
          d3.select(this).selectAll("circle")
          .transition()
          .duration(250)
          .attr("r", circleWidth)
          .attr("fill",palette.pink);

          //TEXT
          d3.select(this).select("text")
          .transition()
          .duration(250)
          .attr("font-size","1em")
          .attr("x", 8 )
          .attr("y", 4 )
        }
      })

      .call(force.drag);


    //CIRCLE
    node.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { **return d.x** })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { **return d.y;** })
      .attr("r", circleWidth)
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) { if (i>0) { return  palette.pink; } else { return palette.paleryellow } } )

    //TEXT
    node.append("text")
      .text(function(d, i) { return d.name; })
    .attr("x",    function(d, i) { return circleWidth + 5; })
      .attr("y",            function(d, i) { if (i>0) { return circleWidth + 0 }    else { return 8 } })
      .attr("font-family",  "Bree Serif")
      .attr("fill",         function(d, i) {  return  palette.paleryellow;  })
      .attr("font-size",    function(d, i) {  return  "1em"; })
      .attr("text-anchor",  function(d, i) { if (i>0) { return  "beginning"; }      else { return "end" } })



force.on("tick", function(e) {
  node.attr("transform", function(d, i) {     
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; 
    });

   link.attr("x1", function(d)   { return d.source.x; })
       .attr("y1", function(d)   { return d.source.y; })
       .attr("x2", function(d)   { return d.target.x; })
       .attr("y2", function(d)   { return d.target.y; })
});

force.start();
```

Comment: they are properties generated by the force engine, you can set them also if you want to start at specific positions

Comment: So they are picked up to have the best layout? How to set them.

Comment: No, the force engine needs to give the nodes a position and speed to simulate, No need to use them in the construction of the circles, only in the `tick` method, you transform the `g` so set the `cx` and `cy` to 0

Comment: Related, almost a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42047027/5768908 . This one uses `d3.layout.cluster()`, while yours use `d3.layout.force()`, but the principle is the same.

Comment: @rioV8 can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

if you stick a `console.log(d);` inside that section where the return is you will see the extra data that the force layout has added. this data is used to position the nodes. its not something you set manually unless you want to manually position individual nodes based on some logic.